# Button firing only once Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get a button to fire more than once(I.e. multiple clicks) but it seems to not be working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Theoretically it should fire multiple times but it only fires once when I check it in the logs

```
function a 
{
...
 var addcolumnspanel = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId("addcolumnspanel");
  var addbuttonhandler = app.createServerHandler("addcolumn");
  var addbutton = app.createButton().setId("btnaddcolumn").setText("Add another column").addClickHandler(addbuttonhandler);  

...
return app;
}

function addcolumn()
{
...//Do some stuff
return app;
}
```

Here is a more precise code example

```
//set global var
var counter = 1; 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//Set up the Menu bar 
function onOpen() {
//  Logger.clear();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "demo", functionName: "myFunction"}];
  ss.addMenu("Demo", menuEntries);

}

function myFunction() {

  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(430).setWidth(800);;
  var button = myapp.createButton("Clicky");
  var myhandler = myapp.createServerHandler("secondfunction");
  var myhandler = button.addClickHandler(myhandler)
  myapp.add(button);
  ss.show(myapp);
}

function secondfunction()
{
  counter++;
   Logger.log(counter);

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'fire more than once' ? The addcolumn() function is called only when the user manually clicks the button

Comment: Yes it only fires the first time I click it.  Meaning every second time I click it doesn't fire.

Comment: More code please! The problem is probably on that "Do some stuff" line...

Comment: Done.  This example doesn't seem to work.  It should increase my counter but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The problem is with the counter variable. You cannot use global variables that way in Apps Script. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549085/using-and-modifying-global-variables-within-handler-functions) for more information. You can use ScriptProperties or CacheService as an alternative.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//Set up the Menu bar 
function onOpen() {
//  Logger.clear();
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "demo", functionName: "myFunction"}];
  ss.addMenu("Demo", menuEntries);
  // Store your counter in CacheService as a string.
  CacheService.getPrivateCache().put('counter','1',3600); 
}

function myFunction() {

  var myapp = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(430).setWidth(800);;
  var button = myapp.createButton("Clicky");
  var myhandler = myapp.createServerHandler("secondfunction");
  var myhandler = button.addClickHandler(myhandler)
  myapp.add(button);
  ss.show(myapp);
}

function secondfunction()
{
   var cache = CacheService.getPrivateCache();
   var counter = parseInt(cache.get('counter'));
   counter ++; 
   cache.put('counter', counter.toString());
   Logger.log(counter);

}
```

Comment: Yes this is correct.  it doesn't work so well in cacheservice, works fine in ScriptProperties but coming from an SQL world I am still struggling with ScriptDB syntax: for instance storing a value ob = {counter:1} and then trying to get that back out and update the value without pulling the whole db with .query({})  A pointer would be helpful but thanks for clarifying that up.  Weird globals aren't really globals in the sense we normally think of in traditional programming.