# how to get value of Hidden object

Tags: google-apps-script

I need global variable in google script, to hold page ID, like a string. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549085/using-and-modifying-global-variables-within-handler-functions), they suggested to use object Hidden for this purpose. I can create this object and set its value.

**Code to achieve the same :**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  //Get current indentificator
  var mid = 'page-id';
  app.add( app.createHidden('mid').setValue(mid).setId('mid'));
  return app;
}
```

But how can I get this value from another function?

**For example :**

```
function maketbl(){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.(?!)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the maketbl function ? Is it a handler ?

Comment: not it isn't handler. You can imagine that it is just function, which is called from big batch of handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your requirement is to have functionality similar to that of global variables. I suggest that you use script properties, user properties or the cache service to accomplish this feat. An example is below

```
ScriptProperties.setProperty('special', 'sauce'); // Use this to set the property
var specialValue = ScriptProperties.getProperty('special'); // use this to access the property
```

Comment: Thank you @AbhishekRam! It works! Can I use this for save objects? For example: ScriptProperties.setProperty('special', {'a':1,'b':2, 'c':3}); and then var specialValue = ScriptProperties.getProperty('special'); specialValue['a'];

Comment: The setProperty accepts only strings so the trick here is save the object as string ScriptProperties.setProperty('special', '{'a':1,'b':2, 'c':3}') and then access it like var specialValue = JSON.parse(ScriptProperties.getProperty('special')) and when resaving using thr stringify function.

Answer (score 0):

Try the bellow code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();  
  var mid = 'page-id';
  var hidden = app.createHidden('mid').setValue(mid).setId('mid');
  app.add(hidden);

  //Create your handler
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('maketbl');
  handler.addCallbackElement(hidden)

  //Create a button to trigger your function
  app.add(app.createButton().setText("go forest").addClickHandler(handler));

  return app;
}

function maketbl(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  //Retrieve the hidden field
  var hidden = app.getElementById("mid");

  //Show the value stored at e.parameter.mid  where mid is the name of the field
  var dialogBox  = app.createDialogBox().setText(e.parameter.mid);  

  dialogBox.setPopupPosition(100, 100);   
  dialogBox.show();
  return app;
}
```

Live version [here](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1orWxMj-MmWhscAh8j3wjk_0B-Gi_cV3gMwAzOts6WmEyzqyP8vjWxPlM/edit?template=default&folder=0B0kQD4hSd4KASUJKb2cya0NET1U&usp=drive_web).

Comment: Thank you br araujo! But how I can get value if my function isn't callback? Is possible to reach this value without making handler?

Comment: Do you mean via javascript?

Comment: in Javascript I can use global variables, but in google apps they don't work, unfortunately. So I have to use Hidden object to save some parameters inside uiapp. I hadn't found any way to get this parameter using UiInstance.

Comment: Global variables work like a charm in GAS. I'd rather think that you misunderstand something. If you stay in the same thread you can use global variables. If you change threads you have a callback. BTW you should add a setName("mid") to above code :)

Comment: BTW: I don't think so... here the Class UiInstance documentation: createHidden(name)

Creates a new Hidden with a specified name.